# curl: (18) transfer closed with 2 bytes remaining to read

Tags: ubuntu, curl, data-transfer-objects, gopro

I used the commands GOPro staff sent me 6 months ago to take pictures/video using the Gopro Hero3 via terminal ( on Gopro Network). It worked. However, I've been trying to do this again in the past month and the following error keeps showing up:

```
**curl: (18) transfer closed with 2 bytes remaining to read**

I have used the following commands:
```

To start a capture, type curl http:// 10.5.5.9/backpac/SH?t=goprohero\&p=%01
To stop a capture (recording a video), type curl http:// 10.5.5.9/backpac/SH?t=goprohero\&p=%00

```
knowing that the following numbers are for the following operations.



   %Video: p=%00 
    -%Photo: p=%01
    -%Time-lapse: p=%03
```

I don't know if I need to change the commands and/or If I need to use wireshark to get them. I need to be able to write a code to get pictures at different time intervals. I know that is a problem with server but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Can anyone please comment on this?
```

Answer (score 0):

start capture should be like `http://10.5.5.9/bacpac/SH?t=goprohero\&p=%01`

and stop capture would be `http://10.5.5.9/bacpac/SH?t=goprohero\&p=%00`

the *2 remaining bytes to read* are command response, the first byte represents command execution status (**0** as **OK** and **2** as **Busy**)

for more information about commands you can refer to https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack

and for implementation reference to https://github.com/r1pper/GoPro.Hero which is a PCL library in c# and should work with mono on ubuntu.